# How to display value with '%' react chart-race

Tags: reactjs

i want to display at chart-race value with percentage. example 75%
however, the value of chart-race accepts only number. how would I able to include '%'

here's the code from 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chart-race'

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChartRace from 'react-chart-race';

  class Form extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
    setInterval(() => {
      this.handleChange();
    }, 0);
  }

  getRandomInt(min, max){
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  handleChange(){
    const data = [
      { id: 0, title: 'Ayfonkarahisar', value: 10, color: '#50c4fe'},
      { id: 1, title: 'Kayseri', value: 20, color: '#3fc42d' },
      { id: 2, title: 'Muğla', value: 30, color: '#c33178' },
      { id: 3, title: 'Uşak', value: 40, color: '#423bce' },
      { id: 4, title: 'Sivas', value: 50, color: '#c8303b' },
      { id: 5, title: 'Konya', value: 60, color: '#2c2c2c' }
    ];
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <ChartRace
          data={this.state.data}
          backgroundColor='#000'
          width={760}
          padding={12}
          itemHeight={58}
          gap={12}
          titleStyle={{ font: 'normal 400 13px Arial', color: '#fff' }}
          valueStyle={{ font: 'normal 400 11px Arial', color: 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.42)' }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export {Form}
```

Comment: i think they provide  label prop for this type of requirement.check their main doc

Comment: Hi @PrakashKarena, already tried putting label inside data variable object, still not showing

Comment: are you using react-chart-race or chart-race-react ??

Comment: Hi @PrakashKarena, Im using react-chart-race

Comment: react-chart-race or chart-race-react ?

Comment: react-chart-race

Comment: provide your chart online on sendbox or codepane i'll check

Comment: please take a look of this image. thankyou https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMbR6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in react-chart-race for label

Now, you do not need to use this dependency use below code in your project

Add this two files to your project

ChartRace.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./chartstyle.css";

export default class ChartRace extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value),
      temp: this.props.data,
      maxValue: Math.max.apply(Math, this.props.data.map(item => item.value)),
      valueLabel: this.props.valueLabel
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    let newProps = [...nextProps.data];
    return {
      data: nextProps.data,
      temp: newProps.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value),
      maxValue: Math.max.apply(Math, nextProps.data.map(item => item.value))
    };
  }

  draw(item, index) {
    const indis = this.state.temp.findIndex(temp => temp.id === item.id);
    const translateY =
      indis === 0
        ? this.props.padding
        : this.props.padding +
          indis * this.props.itemHeight +
          indis * this.props.gap;
    return (
      <div
        key={index}
        className="raceItem"
        style={{
          height: this.props.itemHeight,
          transform:
            "translateY(" +
            translateY +
            "px) translateX(" +
            this.props.padding +
            "px)"
        }}
      >
        <b
          style={{
            backgroundColor: item.color,
            width:
              (item.value / this.state.maxValue) *
              (this.props.width - 120 - 2 * this.props.padding)
          }}
        />
        <span>
          <em style={this.props.titleStyle}>{item.title}</em>
          <i style={this.props.valueStyle}>
            {item.value} {this.state.valueLabel}{" "}
          </i>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="raceArea"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor,
          paddingTop: this.props.padding,
          paddingBottom: this.props.padding,
          width: this.props.width,
          height:
            2 * this.props.padding +
            this.state.temp.length * this.props.itemHeight +
            (this.state.temp.length - 1) * this.props.gap
        }}
      >
        {this.state.data.map((item, index) => this.draw(item, index))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ChartRace.defaultProps = {
  data: [],
  backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9",
  width: 680,
  padding: 20,
  itemHeight: 38,
  gap: 4,
  titleStyle: { font: "normal 400 13px Arial", color: "#212121" },
  valueStyle: { font: "normal 400 11px Arial", color: "#777" },
  valueLabel: ""
};
```

chartstyle.css

```
.raceArea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.raceItem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 1200ms;
}
.raceItem b {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 600ms;
  background: #dadada;
}
.raceItem span {
  width: 112px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.raceItem em {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.raceItem i {
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Import it like

```
import ChartRace from "./ChartRace";
```

Use it like

```
       <ChartRace
          data={this.state.data}
          backgroundColor="#000"
          width={760}
          padding={12}
          itemHeight={58}
          gap={12}
          valueLabel="%"  // pass your label here 
          titleStyle={{ font: "normal 400 13px Arial", color: "#fff" }}
          valueStyle={{
            font: "normal 400 11px Arial",
            color: "rgba(255,255,255, 0.42)"
          }}
        />
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-feistel-277q5 live example

Comment: but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."